# Обращение к дочерному объекту из дочерного объекта

Tags: c#, xamarin

У меня есть  StackLayout в котором храниться ImageButton,Label, и еще один StackLayout в котором еще 2 Label, надо чтобы при нажатии на ImageButton, я мог в string a присвоить текст из Label который находится в основном StackLayout

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
    <Image BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="150" Margin="0,-18,0,0" Source="https://cdn.sushiwok.ru/img/a6ca1d32cffce82567a213237e1bb9da/350x350"></Image>
        <Label Margin="0,-18,0,0" FontFamily="Lobster" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black">Суши Острый Угорь 2 шт</Label>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Margin="5,-15,0,0" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="25">199 р.</Label>
                <Label Margin="5,-10,0,0" TextColor="LightGray"  FontSize="20">̶2̶5̶0̶ ̶р̶.̶</Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <ImageButton Clicked="Buy_Clicked_2" Margin="20,0,0,0" Source="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/770722183957577789/952982843158581288/free-icon-bags-6997133.png" BackgroundColor="White"></ImageButton>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Я пробывал вот этот метод:

```
foreach (var child in ((sender as ImageButton).Parent as StackLayout).Children)
            {
                if (child is Label)
                {
                    child.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: А почему вы используете XAML, как источник данных? Все ваши цены, картинки и прочее, должны быть в C# коде, в виде простых коллекций, классов, свойств, которые в свою очередь **привязаны** в XAML. А сейчас вы просто делаете ерунду, используете UI, как источник данных. Это не знаю, если вы допустим задаете тут, на SO, вопрос, но весь текст пишете в фотошопе, сохраняете в виде картинки и отсылаете сюда. Сравнение конечно грубое, но думаю вы понимаете, что делаете бред. А так, ну задайте лейблу имя и через него получайте данные.

Comment: Спасибо, я не думал про это, впредь не буду так делать

Comment: Вы хоть поняли как это должно все быть устроено, или так, от балды сказали "не буду так делать"? На всякий разъясню: Вот у вас есть продукт, суши, делаете класс `Product`, у продукта есть название, цена, цена со скидкой, картинка, вот это вы и делаете в классе в виде **свойство** (`public int Price {get; private set;} ...`). Далее делаете еще один класс, который будет являтся основным источником данных, в нем делаете свойство с коллекцией продуктов и заполняете ее. Далее, задаете окну `DataContext` (или что там в Xamarin) на класс, где коллекция продуктов. Остается в XAML привязать все.